# Button width as a percentage of parent

Tags: html, css

I want to my button to spread out 90% of the width of my screen.

When I run my HTML, the button is just about 10% of the screen. However, if I set the width to a number with pixels, it resizes fine.

What's going wrong?

```css
.quiz {
  /*top: 240px;*/
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
}

.quiz button {
  width: 90%;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <button>Option 1</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set a percentage height, its parent element must have an explicit height.

In your case, the best way to do this is to add `width: 100%` to `.quiz`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you are taking the width of an element's parent.  You will need to set the parent container of button to 100% of the screen, then surround your other elements in a separate container inside quiz.

Answer (score 0):

When you give 90% width to the button, it considers the width of div.quiz as the maximum and gives button 90% of that width.
If button has to be 90% of the screen, either define it directly inside body or change the div.quiz width to 100% and it should be inside body or another element which has same width as body.

```
.quiz {
    top: 240px;
    width: 100%;   ---assuming its parent has width that body has.
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
}

.quiz button {
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The width of your div `quiz` is just fitting the button's size. And the button takes 90% of your div's size.
So, if you want the button to take 90% of your screen, you should tell your div to be 100% of your screen.

```css
.quiz {
    top: 240px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
}

.quiz button {
    width: 90%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
    <button>Option 1</button>
</div>
```

This should work properly :)