# Getting size of previously rendered image for image overlay

Tags: html, css, visual-web-developer

i am looking for a way to get the size of a rendered image within a webpage, which size is defined as a percentage value.
I need this because of a relative positioning of 2 images which should be invariant go the size of the browser window, as well as the zooming of the site.

I did some research and this one here describes my problem pretty well:

[Button width as a percentage of parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45923542/button-width-as-a-percentage-of-parent)

Quote:

*"To set a percentage height, its parent element must have an explicit height."*

Here are the relevant parts of my project:

```
<div style="display: block; width:90%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(128,128,0,0.5)">

<button style=@myStyle @onclick="@(e => doFunction(5))"> </button>
```

with myStyle:

```
myStyle = "top: -30%; left: 0%; width: 15%; height: 15%; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgba(201, 76, 76, 0.3); position: relative;"
```

**So, i got the button within a  structure, and the size of the  structure is again given as a percentage with respect to its superordinate structure. (but this topmost structure then has absolute values).**

Is there a way to calculating and getting the absolute values (width/height) of the first  structure "while rendering"?

I hope i could explain my problem sufficiently understandable, i'm happy about any answers regarding this problem, even if the answer is "it does not work like that". Thanks!

Comment: Can you try to describe what exactly you're trying to achieve? It's probably possible to do without calculating dimensions of the image. You want to create an element which has some width, and height should equal some percentage of the width?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

Give your image an ID:

```
<div id="some-id" style="display: block; width:90%; height:100%; background-color:rgba(128,128,0,0.5)">
```

In JavaScript, set an Event Listener when the window is loaded:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    //set the image's dimensions to the divs that need it
    var imageDiv = document.getElementById("some-id");
    var otherDiv = document.getElementById("other-div");

    otherDiv.style.height = imageDiv.offsetHeight + "px";
    otherDiv.style.width = imageDiv.offsetWidth + "px";
});
```

Comment: I forgot to ask if you are allowed to use Javascript. Are you?